# How can I save a buffer in Emacs without visiting it?

Tags: file, emacs, save

The built-in command **list-buffers** creates a buffer called ***Buffer List*** which can be saved to a file using *C-x C-s*.  Is there some way to automate this so that I can enter something like **list-buffers-to-file** and have the output file created automatically, without having to leave the buffer I'm working in?

When I execute **list-buffers**, the window I'm working in is split and a buffer named ***Buffer List*** appears in the lower pane.  I then have to *C-x o* to move to the *Buffer List* buffer and save it, then *C-x o* back to the buffer I was working in and type *C-x 1* to remove the other pane.  I would like to avoid the splitting of the window, and actually do not need to see the ***Buffer List*** buffer at all, but I cannot figure out how to do this.  All of the buffer-saving elisp commands seem to work on the current buffer only, which means having to leave the buffer I'm working in.  There doesn't seem to be a command like **save-other-buffer** *buffer-name* *file-to-save-in*.  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```lisp
(defun save-buf-list (&optional arg)
  "Write `list-buffers' output to file `~/somewhere/my-buflist.txt'.
A prefix arg is handled as in `list-buffers'."
  (interactive "P")
  (with-current-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg)
    (write-file "~/somewhere/my-buflist.txt")))
```

If you want to be able to write the buffers to different files, you can add an arg for the `FILE` and prompt for that first.

To find this for yourself, check the code defining `list-buffers` (`C-h f list-buffers`, then click the file name). That command is defined with just this code:

```lisp
(display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg))
```

So you know that `list-buffers-noselect` must return a buffer (which is what `display-buffer` needs). And `C-h f` list-buffers-noselect` confirms this.

Then all you need to know is how to write a given buffer to a given file.  `write-file` writes the *current* buffer to a file.  And macro `with-current-buffer` does stuff with a given buffer current.

Comment: This code does exactly what I need.  What was confusing for me is what "current" means in "current buffer".  I naively assumed it referred to the buffer I am in when I execute a command, but from your code I see that I was mistaken.  It apparently means whatever buffer is within the scope of "(with-current-buffer ...)" where the ellipsis denotes a piece of code that returns some buffer.